# Small overlapping text on Related questions in MSE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, sidebar

Just noticed a minor css issue on this question:

[Math Stackexchange said "We are Offline" until I reset my router - Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233579/math-stackexchange-said-we-are-offline-until-i-reset-my-router-why)

The related questions on the right hand side have some overlapping text in Chrome:

> [image]

(This only applies to this very site, Meta Stack Exchange)

Comment: Result of fixing [this more severe bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229751/related-questions-with-over-99-score-display-incorrectly).

Comment: This can't be closed as dupe of a completed report, it makes no sense.

Comment: The other report you linked to is about Stack Overflow. Different CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be fixed now with the new design as of today:

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a side-effect of the (partial) fix to [Related questions with over 99 score display incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229751/related-questions-with-over-99-score-display-incorrectly), which was resolved by preventing multi-digit question scores from wrapping onto multiple lines.  However, now they overflow their boxes horizontally instead:

[image: Screenshot of overflowing question score]

Adding the following extra CSS rules would fix the problem by making the boxes wider for three- and four-digit scores (like they are on SO, for example):

```css
#sidebar .answer-votes.large { width: 32px !important }
#sidebar .answer-votes.extra-large { font-size: 11px !important; width: 32px !important }
```

<sub>(The `!important` tags are only there because the existing styles use them.  IMO, it would be better to clean up the CSS and get rid of them, as well as the fossil layers of conflicting rules that are their presumed *raison d'être*.)</sub>

The result would look like this:

[image: Screenshot with suggested fix]

(Ps. The second screenshot above is taken using [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), which already includes this CSS fix.)

Comment: I'm sure Jin is going to appreciate the spoon feeding. ;-)