# 4-Digit rep up Bug in Mobile Device?

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web

Referring to [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5666987/ian?tab=topactivity). (in mobile theme - in case the profile's front page is changed in the future, the issue is originated from [this (stackoverflow) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827659/compiling-an-application-for-use-in-highly-radioactive-environments/36831344#36831344))

The 4-digit reputation up seems to be little overlapping with the boundary, but only only when opened using mobile device:

[image]

The look on the desktop is fine. Related post which fixes the bug on the desktop:

[Small overlapping text on Related questions in MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233606/small-overlapping-text-on-related-questions-in-mse)

My mobile device is Android (if that matters). I browse using Chrome.