# I can't log into Super User

Tags: support, login

I keep seeing activity happening on Super User (via the glowing favicon and the banner that says how many questions have new activity), but when I try to log in, it keeps saying that that feature is unavailable because of site maintenance.

Is there actual maintenance going on; and if so, why is there activity being registered, when (according the page that I keep landing on) the site's supposed to be in read only mode?

I'm using Firefox on Windows 7 Enterprise.

This also applies to Meta Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear your browser's cache or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> in your browser.

If that resolves it, it was a DNS caching issue similar to [Math Stackexchange said "We are Offline" until I reset my router - Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233579/math-stackexchange-said-we-are-offline-until-i-reset-my-router-why)